# Javascript get img src and show link in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm just a beginner in javascript, I'm trying to make javascript take image src from specific image with a specific class and place the src into div.

```
<div class="result"></div>
<div class="ilist">
<a href="#"><img src="images/dog.jpg" class="thumbnail"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/bird.jpg" class="thumbnail"></a>
<img src="images/cat.jpg" class="selected__img">  // THIS IS THE DESIRED IMAGE
</div>
```

What i want to show in the result div is this = images/cat.jpg
but instead it doesn't display anything or some weird stuff...

javascript right now

```
var simg = document.getElementsByClassName('selected__img').src;
document.getElementsByClassName("result").innerHTML = simg;
```

Sorry for being such a newbie but I'm trying to learn..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

Try this:

```
   <script>
        var simg = document.getElementsByClassName('selected__img');
        var src=simg[0].src;
        var resutlObj=document.getElementsByClassName("result")[0]
        resutlObj.innerHTML = src;
    </script>
```

Full code snippet:

```js
var simg = document.getElementsByClassName('selected__img');
var src = simg[0].src;
var resutlObj = document.getElementsByClassName("result")[0]
resutlObj.innerHTML = src;
```

```html
<div class="result"></div>
<div class="ilist">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/100?random=1" class="thumbnail"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/100/100?random=2" class="thumbnail"></a>
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200?random=3" class="selected__img"> // THIS IS THE DESIRED IMAGE
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` is a NodeList collection. So you need to take individual nodes with `[0]`:

```
var simg = document.getElementsByClassName('selected__img')[0].src;
document.getElementsByClassName("result")[0].innerHTML = simg;
```

In this specifc case it's more convenient to use `querySelector` metod which returns one element:

```
var simg = document.querySelector('.selected__img').src;
document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = simg;
```

or since you are using jQuery:

```
var simg = $('.selected__img').attr('src');
$(".result").text(simg);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('img').hover(function(){
    $('.result').html($(this).attr('src'));
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result">Image path</div>
<div class="ilist">
<a href="#"><img src="images/dog.jpg" class="thumbnail"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/bird.jpg" class="thumbnail"></a>
<img src="images/cat.jpg" class="selected__img">  // THIS IS THE DESIRED IMAGE
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over elements, since you have one `selected__img` you can use 0 like below:

```
var simg = document.getElementsByClassName('selected__img')[0].src;
document.getElementsByClassName("result").innerHTML = simg;
```